# Need assistance printing out a number from another method

Tags: java

I am working on a small RPG project and I can't print a number from another method.

Here's the main:

```
///////// SMTMain /////////

//Note: this is a parody game and not to be meant for actual retail purposes.

// SMTMain.java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SMTMain
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    SMTBattle battle = new SMTBattle();//runs the battle method, works fine.
    SMTStats stats = new SMTStats();

    //battle.battle(); commented out battle until i can get stats working
    System.out.print(stats.pcstats(str));
    //error, cannot find symbol    ^

   } // end main
} // end class SMTMain
```

And the file containing all the stats:

```
 ///////// SMTStats /////////

 // SMTStats.java

 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class SMTStats
 {

  Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

  ////////Main Stats///////////////
 private int lvl; //level
 private double str; //strength
 private double agi; //agility
 private double itl; //intellect
 private double wis; //wisdom
 private double lk; //luck
 //////Main Stats end/////////////

///////stats that are influenced by main stats or gear/////////
 private double hp; // health
 private double mp; //mana
 private double arm; //armor
 private double atk; //attack
 private double crit; //critical
 private double hit; //chance to hit
 private double def; //defense
 private double dge; //dodge
 ////////stats etc. ends//////////////////////////////////

 double pcstats; //player character function

 public double pcstats() //player character stats
 {
   //int lvl = 1; //worried about just str currently
   double str = 10.0;
   /*agi = 10;
   itl = 10;
   wis = 10;
   lk = 10;
   hp = 30;
   mp = 30;
   arm = 30;
   atk = 1.2 * str;
   crit = (1.5 * lk) / 2;
   hit = 1.5 * (agi * 2);
   def = arm / str;
   dge = (agi * 1);*/

   return pcstats;
 }
} // end class SMTStats
```

I tried googling my error but I couldn't find an answer to my question and I'm still fairly new to java programming, I was hoping y'all would lead me into the right direction.

Comment: Oh, you need to have setters and getters for all your attributes.  Then call the getter method on the attribute you want to print out.

Comment: What happens if you put a print statement in your pcstats() method?

Comment: you need to define str in your main method before you pass it on to pcstats method. I think instead of this you should make getter and setter and then play around with them as suggested by hooknc

Comment: well what is    str?  you are passing it but what is it? you need to give it a value?

Comment: You'll also need to modify your method signature if you're going to include a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

#### What Java tries to do:

Java tries to find some Variable called **str**. But **SMTMain** has no variable called **str**. The class **SMTMain** can't "see" what you have declared in another class (**SMTStats**).

---

#### What you are probably trying to do:

The variable **stats** is an object (so called instance of the class) of the class **SMTStats**.
You need one more method (function of an Object) in the class **SMTStats**. 
Usually, you make so called **getter** and **setter** methods.

---

### Code:

The getter for str in **SMTStats**:

```
public int getStr() {
    return str;
}
```

The method getStr() returns the variable str to **SMTMain**.

---

The setter for str in **SMTStats**:

```
public void setStr(double newStr) {
    str = newStr;
}
```

The method setStr sets the variable from **SMTMain**.

---

In the class **SMTMain** you can now print the variable str from **SMTStats**:

```
System.out.print(stats.getStr());
```

The name of the getter method implies what variable you want to get/return.

---

A nice **java tutorial** by the way (**Chapter 25** is Object Oriented Programming):
http://chortle.ccsu.edu/java5/index.html